# RSS with only .torrent links for newly released FOSS .iso files?

Tags: bittorrent, bandwidth

Is there a freely accessible RSS feed such that 
(1) it exclusively consists of direct .torrent links for newly released FOSS software, and
(2) the feed can be parsed by utorrent or a similar free bittorrent client for automatic download and seeding, and
(3) the RSS is provided by a well established participant in the FOSS ecosystem
?

Background: Such a feed would be a simple means for people to donate spare upload bandwith to FOSS projects. But the question is practically answerable without debate or discussion of that background.

Answer (score 1):

Use Deluge with an RSS plugin, such as YaRSS2: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins/YaRSS2

You may be able to get the info you want from DistroWatch's RSS feeds: http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=faq

But you may have to parse the RSS body text rather than just the URL if the URL doesn't link to the torrent... that may require use of one of the other Deluge plugins or write your own... http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins

Noble idea; in the past I've donated terabytes of bandwidth to Ubuntu and Fedora from my dedi server.